# Message when browsing with incompatible Browser

Tags: browser, message

I wonder some jquery features are not displayed (correctly) at Internet Explorer 6 like the ui.slider. Is there a chance not to display the real jquery code of the site if its opened with a "underdeveloped" Browser? Instead of showing the real jquery code, a message with "Get a compatible Browser" or something like that should show up.

I guess I will need the hide option, but how can I determine with the code which browser is not compatible so that the message is only shown for this class of browsers?

Answer (score 2):

you should never display such a message. gracefully degrade instead.

Answer (score 0):

just use "jQuery.Browser"

[JQuery Browser Detection](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser.version)

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
  alert(parseInt(jQuery.browser.version));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For filtering to different IE
   versions use IE's conditional
   comments feature.
2. There are [slider
   implementations](http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_slider_control/docs/) that do work for
   back-version IE that could be
   substituted as needed.